# Selection Sort with Linked List C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, selection-sort

Im trying order my Linked List by selection sort, but i have a problem with swap between pointer atual and next(proximo), my function **ordena** dont work. How I doing this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Candidato{
    int nota;
    char nome[200];
    char cpf[11];
    struct Candidato *proximo;

};

struct TipoListaCandidato{
    Candidato *inicio = NULL;
    Candidato *fim = NULL;
};

void iniciaCandidato(TipoListaCandidato *pLista){
    pLista->inicio = NULL;
    pLista->fim = NULL;
} 

TipoListaCandidato lista;

void inserirCandidato(TipoListaCandidato *pLista){
    int nota;
    char nome[200],cpf[11];

    Candidato *aux = pLista->inicio;

    Candidato *novoNodo = new Candidato;


    printf("Digite nome: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nome);

    printf("Digite cpf: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(cpf);

    printf("Digite nota: ");
    scanf("%d",&novoNodo->nota);

    strcpy(novoNodo->cpf,cpf);
    strcpy(novoNodo->nome,nome);

    novoNodo->proximo = NULL;

    if(aux == NULL){
        pLista->inicio = novoNodo;
        pLista->fim = novoNodo;

    }else{
        aux = pLista->fim;
        pLista->fim = novoNodo;
        aux->proximo = pLista->fim;
    }
}

TipoListaCandidato ordenado;


void ordena(TipoListaCandidato *pLista){
    Candidato *aux = pLista->inicio,*seguinte,*tmp;
    for(;aux != NULL;aux = aux->proximo){
            Candidato *minimo = aux;
            for(seguinte = aux->proximo;seguinte !=NULL; seguinte = seguinte->proximo){
                if(seguinte->nota > minimo->nota){
                    minimo = seguinte;
                }
            }
            tmp = aux;
            aux = minimo;
            minimo = tmp;
            //tmp->proximo = aux->proximo;
            //minimo->proximo = tmp;
        }
}
```

I would like how i make the swap between pointers, help me pls.

Att

Comment: If this is supposed to be C then you're missing some declarations.  What is type `TipoListaCandidato`, for example?  In C, having a struct with that *tag* does not automatically give you a type with that *name*.

Comment: This looks suspicious: `if(seguinte->nota > minimo->nota){ minimo = seguinte; }`.  My Spanish (Portuguese?) isn't so good, but if `minimo` is supposed to end up as a pointer to the least element in the current sublist then you have the comparison backwards,

Answer (score 0):

Do note my comments on the question, but the main problem with your sort function appears to be that you don't ever perform any actual swaps.  I suppose this code is *meant* to do a swap ...

```
        tmp = aux;
        aux = minimo;
        minimo = tmp;
```

... but it just swaps values of your tracking variables, not the positions of the pointed-to nodes in your list.  You need to adjust the `proximo` pointers of your `struct Candidato` objects to swap list elements.  This is a bit tricky, especially with a singly-linked list such as yours.

Additionally, with a linked list you don't really need to swap *per se*.  At each step just remove the minimum element from its current position in the sublist and re-insert it at the beginning of the sublist.  That's actually going to be a lot easier to manage than a *bona fide* swap.